# Unable to lo load symbols table and perform symbolic debugging with Simics

Tags: simics

I'm trying to debug my custom kernel under Simics preview 6.0.43.
I'm able to boot the kernel, set a breakpoint on a memory address and to have the execution hit the breakpoint.
Anyway I'm not able to load symbols for symbolic debugging.
This what I did:

```
simics> $disk0_image="/home/peppe/Scrivania/gpt.img"
simics> 
simics> run-command-file /opt/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.43/targets/qsp-x86/qsp-h
dd-boot.simics

simics> enable-debugger
Debugger enabled.
simics> 
simics> add-symbol-file /home/peppe/Scrivania/g-os-grub2/g-os/kernel.bin
Context query * currently matches 6 contexts.
Symbol file added with id '1'.

simics> bp.source_location.break 0xc0000812
2: 0x2 (planted)
simics> bp.source_location.break kmain
3: 0x3 (not planted)
simics> list kamin.c
**At col 7: Cannot read symbol data. Invalid abbreviation table offset. Error reading DWARF data**

simics> run
running> 
[tcf] Breakpoint 2 on execution in context mb.cpu0.core[0][0]
Now debugging the x86QSP1 board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]
??()
                                                  push ebp
simics> board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0].pregs

rip = 0x00000000c0000812
```

I compiled my source with:

```
CFLAGS         = -O0 -g -c -fno-builtin -m32
gcc version 11.2.1 20211203 (Red Hat 11.2.1-7) (GCC)
```

My question: why the error message

```
At col 7: Cannot read symbol data. Invalid abbreviation table offset. Error reading DWARF data
```

that seems to prevent correct accessing to symbols?

Comment: Adding Simics target is x64 whereas the code is 32 bit compiled. Could be that the reason of the issue?

Comment: I answer to myself. The problem has to to do with DWARF version. My gcc uses version 5 by default and that seems not be recognized by Simics. Switching to lower version it work out.

Comment: 6.0.126 was released on March 9

Answer (score 1):

Simics is supposed to support Dwarf 5 but you need to upgrade to at least 6.0.116, and 6.0.126 was released on March 9.